# GeoServer MBStyle extension: The style specifies an attribute named 'class', not found in the workspace:lines layer

Tags: geoserver, style

I copied a mapbox style from [github](https://github.com/openmaptiles/maptiler-basic-gl-style/blob/master/style.json) and want to use that to style a geoserver map. So I went to add the style but in the style preview tab I get this error:

> The requested style cannot be used with this layer. The style specifies an attribute named 'class', not found in the 'workspace:line' layer

It says the same thing with ever every layer actually.

Classes are used for filtering stuff:

```
"filter": [
   "all",
   ["in", "class", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "trunk"]
],
```

Is there an equivalent to class in GeoServer styling that I replace the classes with?

Comment: In and class look different from all the other things in your list. Are you sure that is right?

Comment: @IanTurton Look the [original mapbox style](https://github.com/openmaptiles/maptiler-basic-gl-style/blob/41c78c26eb3958db105c937390d5a0a4b1e6c77b/style.json#L33) line 33

Comment: The styles that you have are made to work with the OpenMapTiles schema https://openmaptiles.org/schema/. OpenMapTiles do have attribute "class" but that is not any standard and GeoServer does not automatically create MVT tiles with the same attribute schema. The schema and MVT tiles must match. What attributes you do have in your workspace:line layer?

Comment: Uh, thank you. I don't know where to look for the attributes for the layer, I'll try to find them. Am I probably going to make a lot of changes to my styles?